# WPF ComboBox/ComboBoxEdit in Datagrid/GridControl Row ItemsSource from outside row

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid, datasource

i have a DevExpress ComboBoxEdit inside a GridControl.
Afaik ComboBox inside a DataGridRow has the same problem.

EditValue is inside the row-object:

```
EditValue="{Binding Row.Selected}"
```

Thats ok.

Currently the ItemsSource = List of all possible options is also inside the row-object.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Row.AllPossibilities}"
```

It works but i don't like to clutter the object too much - it has then to contain lists of every possible option for most of the properties.

Thats why i what to chance the ItemsSource to be in the DataContext of the WPF UserControl instead the DataContext of the GridControl inside the UserControl.

I tried setting the ItemsSource with Path and name in the UserControl DataContext but got XAML-Bindingerror that the Property is not found in object of type "EditGridCellData"

Is that even possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=AllPossibilities,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```